# How to take all the names of colums as y-axis and plot them in the same graph with ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

given a data frame like that:

```
   V1  V2  V3  V4 ... V25
1  0.3 0.2 0.0 0.0    0.0
2  0.0 0.0 0.1 0.15   0.0
   ...
```

I'd like to take the row names as x-axis and column names(`V1`:`V25`)as y-axis and plot multiple area plots in the same graph.

So i tried:

```
ggplot(topic_count, aes(x= row.names(topic_count),y = colnames(topic_count),group = colnames(topic_count))) + geom_point()
```

But got `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (22): x, y` error.

Do you know how to do it properly? Thanks.

Comment: what does the expected plot look like?

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, you will want to do something like add the row names (numbers in this case) as a column, then use something like `tidyr` to reshape the data frame. Example using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, `topic_count <- topic_count %>% mutate(row_names = row_number())` and `topic_count_deep <- topic_count %>% gather(cnames, cvals, -row_names)'.  You can then plot with `ggplot(tc_deep, aes(row_names, cvals, group = cnames)) + geom_point()`

Comment: @mtoto there should be `25` different plots in on graph, `row.names` as x-asix and `Vn` as y-axis

Comment: @steveb `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'row_names' not found`

Comment: @mtoto Did you run the first command successfully, `topic_count <- topic_count %>% mutate(row_names = row_number())` ? This add the 'row_names'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to melt your `data.frame` first, then we can use `ggplot` with `facet.wrap()` to generate multiple plots in one graph.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df.melted <- melt(as.matrix(df))

ggplot(df.melted, aes(factor(Var1), value)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ Var2)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(0.3, 0), V2 = c(0.2, 0), V3 = c(0, 0.1), 
    V4 = c(0, 0.15)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))
```